# How to correctly migrate an unnormalized and inconsistent user database

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, database-migration

I'm currently working in a startup which somehow neglected their infrastructure and database. 
Our user database is a mess (Thx to WordPress) and I am currently working to migrate it to a PostgreSQL. The problem is that the data is inconsistent. For instance some users don't have a postal address, postal address format change over time, others have their email instead of their phone number for their username...

We found some solution, for instance for the postal address format we geocode with Google Maps API. However, it's clear that we can't have a consistent database with the current data..

So the question is: Do we use another table for the inconsistent users and move them to the "new" table when they will update their account after the first connection or use a single table for all user and make some concessions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to consider:

1. What type of application(s) -> software -> systems is your data going to be used for?   If your application(s) require that your data is normalised (in other words your applications "demand" structured data with primary / foreign key relationships) then you need to represent your data by using a relational database.
2. If you data does not need to be "that structured" - you may be able to use a noSQL database (like https://redis.io/) which stores data by keys -> values (linking a key to a document / data structure).

If you need to use a relational database OR noSQL database:

I would clean your data, and have consistent contact information.

I would get users to update their contact information (the next time they login), and store this "clean contact data in a different table", with a boolean field (which can be user contact data is consistent true/false).

Don't do "concessions" otherwise you will end up with inconsistent data "forever", and (business logic) hacks in your code (which people will forget about) - which will never allow you clean up your data.